# My SQL multiple search criteria

Tags: mysql, search

I have a search query that looks for user clients via email. I would like it to look for first name and surname as well.

```
$list = mysql_query("SELECT    id, 
           user_email, 
           meta_lastname.meta_value lastname,  
           meta_firstname.meta_value firstname 
 FROM      wp_users 
 LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta meta_lastname 
 ON        meta_lastname.user_id = wp_users.id 
 LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta meta_firstname 
 ON        meta_firstname.user_id = wp_users.id 
 WHERE     meta_lastname.meta_key = 'last_name' 
 AND       meta_firstname.meta_key = 'first_name'
    AND user_email LIKE '%$searchpattern%' 
    ORDER BY lastname;");
```

I tried changing the second to last line to

```
AND user_email, lastname, firstname LIKE '%$searchpattern%' 
        ORDER BY lastname;");
```

But that did not work.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you just meant

```
AND 
(
  user_email LIKE '%$searchpattern%' 
  OR lastname LIKE '%$searchpattern%'
  OR firstname   LIKE '%$searchpattern%'
)
```

Comment: Does not seam to have worked. It's causing an error on the ajax which suggests the query is non functional

Comment: Have you tried putting the query into phpmyadmin or something like that to see what the new error message is because technically that is the correct syntax for what you are trying to do.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'lastname' in 'where clause'

Comment: Replace the variables lastname with meta_lastname.meta_value and firstname with meta_firstname.meta_value Then functional

Answer (score 0):

In your WHERE clause, you must refer to table entities, and not entities in your result set.

You probably want:

```
AND 
(
  wp_users.user_email LIKE '%$searchpattern%' 
  OR meta_lastname.meta_value LIKE '%$searchpattern%'
  OR meta_firstname.meta_value LIKE '%$searchpattern%'
)
```

Don't forget to escape $searchpattern with `mysql_real_escape_string` before using it in a query.